# Dynamically including Subtitles to video files in iOS?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

In AVFoundation we can split and merge tracks of any media files. I assume a subtitle to be another track and I want to include this track based on the language the user chooses. My Idea is to include the hardcoded subtitles files as per languages I support in the project and add this subtitle track to the video file I have at run time.
I am not sure if this is possible with AVFoundation. Please direct me to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apple provided example code "avsubtitleswriterOSX" is compatible with iOS 7 and 8. This solved my issue.
[avsubtitleswriterOSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/avsubtitleswriterOSX/Introduction/Intro.html)